# GWT ScrollTable Issue : Header and datatables of the ScrollTable are misaligned when using horizontal scroll

Tags: gwt, gwt2

I have a `ScrollTable` which is populated dynamically. (The rows and columns are calculated on fly and data is populated). My `ScrollTable` supports both horizontal and vertical scroll. When I have a lot of columns and I scroll horizontally to view the data, I see a misalignment in the way `Header` & `DataTables` are rendered.  I suspect GWT rendering is happening slowly and it is causing the issue.

Here goes the code :

```java
public class TestScrollTable implements EntryPoint {

    public FixedWidthGrid dataTable = new FixedWidthGrid(200,20);   
    public FixedWidthFlexTable headerTable = new FixedWidthFlexTable();
    public ScrollTable table = new ScrollTable(dataTable, headerTable);

    @Override
    public void onModuleLoad() {

        table.setColumnResizePolicy(ColumnResizePolicy.SINGLE_CELL);
        table.setResizePolicy(ResizePolicy.UNCONSTRAINED);
        table.setScrollPolicy(ScrollPolicy.BOTH);
        table.setSortPolicy(SortPolicy.SINGLE_CELL);
        RootPanel.get().add(table);

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            headerTable.setHTML(0, i, "Header " + i);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++) {
                final int row = i;
                final int column = j;                         
                dataTable.setHTML(row, column, "Cell " + row + ":" + column);
            }
        }
        table.redraw();
    }

}
```

The issue is not always seen. It is seen when we run the above code and use the web application via remote desktop and sometimes in the deployed version of the application (when I have a lot of columns and I need to scroll horizontally). Pagination and sorting of the data has been taken care of.

I have the below solution as a workaround:

When I resize the header table, the whole `ScrollTable` gets aligned properly. But this, if done programatically might be a performance issue.
If we navigate to other browser tab and return, the issue is not seen.

**Additional Info:**

1. I have tried running the above code using GWT css for `ScrollTable` widget and using my custom CSS.
2. Have tried to use `DeferredCommand` before redrawing the `ScrollTable`.
   The above scenarios have not yielded any results.

My application uses GWT 2.0.4.

Answer (score 0):

`FixedWidthGrid`, `FixedWidthFlexTable` and `ScrollTable` are not widgets of the GWT library, I guess that your application is using gwt-incubator which is a deprecated project used time ago to play with widgets and new things before they were or not integrated into GWT.

Modern GWT versions include improved table widgets like [CellTable](http://gwt.googleusercontent.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellTable) which does not have that issue. I encourage you to migrate your app to last gwt because both: gwt-2.0.4 was released some years ago, and gwt-incubator is not maintained, so it will be difficult to find support from them, I know migration could be a hard task, but I think it is worth. Take a look to this [thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-web-toolkit/asVkaoPwYI0) in the gwt mailing list.